# IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds, sk-learn

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://towardsdatascience.com/using-data-science-to-better-understand-your-customers-part-1-of-2-398d11049785
But when I try to do `X = df.iloc[:, [3, 4]].values` it gives me that error.
How can I solve this?
The dataset:
CustomerID,Gender,Age,Annual Income (k$),Spending Score (1-100)
1,Male,19,15,39
2,Male,21,15,81
3,Female,20,16,6
4,Female,23,16,77
5,Female,31,17,40
6,Female,22,17,76
7,Female,35,18,6
8,Female,23,18,94
9,Male,64,19,3
10,Female,30,19,72
11,Male,67,19,14
12,Female,35,19,99
13,Female,58,20,15
14,Female,24,20,77
15,Male,37,20,13
16,Male,22,20,79
17,Female,35,21,35
18,Male,20,21,66
19,Male,52,23,29
20,Female,35,23,98
21,Male,35,24,35
22,Male,25,24,73
23,Female,46,25,5
24,Male,31,25,73
25,Female,54,28,14
and goes on and on. If someone can help me, I will apprecieate it

Comment: I loaded up the dataset on a Kaggle notebook and couldn't reproduce the error. Are you sure you got the right dataset?

Comment: Yes it is the right dataset